# Determining where the derivative of a function equals zero, will always produce absolute max/min values. T/F?

Tags: calculus

Is this true of false and why?

I believe it is false since when the derivative equals zero, it produces local max/min.
Also endpoints will also give you absolute max/min thus you must check that.

thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that where the derivative is zero the is a local extreme. What is true is the opposite: if there is a local extreme and the function is differentiable around the point, then the derivative is zero.

Think $f(x)=x^3$ at $x=0$.